# Getting the name of file just uploaded in HTML file Input Type

Tags: javascript, html

The user has just chosen a file for upload using the HTML File input tag and clicked the submit button, which then uploads or save the file at the particular location.

I know that you can get the file name, file path, etc. using php (`$_FILES['file']['name']`), but is there a way that I can know the uploaded file's name(only the name, not the complete path) using javascript? is it possible? if yes, how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's possible:

```
<html><body>
<form onsubmit="alert(document.getElementById('up_file').value);">
<input type='file' id='up_file' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks heximal for the solution...lil bit of a prblm over here. If i use this code in FF it displays the image name fine, but if i use chrome, it displays 'C:\fakepath\sunset.jpg'...any thoughts?

Comment: actually it has to show full path to file always. you may extract file name e.g. in this way: document.getElementById('up_file').value.replace(/^.*\\/, '')

Comment: yea i think i have to do the extraction, if i want to make it browser compatible....i wud extract the file name if its chrome n nt if its FF!! is there a way to find out the browser name in javascript?

Comment: yes, there is the way to find out current browser, but in your case there is absolutely no need to extract file name only for some browser. don't complicate, just do it always (extraction)

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be helpful, it takes upload file and shows the name:

document.getElementById('upload').onchange = uploadOnChange;

function uploadOnChange() {

```
var filename = this.value;
var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
}
document.getElementById('filename').value = filename;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/WWNnV/4/